# Mysql database change event

Tags: mysql

I need  to call bash script when mysql database schema has changed. As example queries:

```
ALTER TABLE, CREATE TABLE, DROP TABLE
```

it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run python script on Database event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23382499/run-python-script-on-database-event)

Comment: How soon do you need to know that a change has occurred? You might have to switch to a DBMS that supports DDL triggers if the answer is "instantly"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think that's possible any way. You could have probably use a `DDL Trigger` but MySQL doesn't support one. See worklog https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=2418.

Though you can write a stored procedure to perform the business logic and call that procedure but capturing the DDL event isn't possible AFAIK. You should also check on [Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html) in MySQL