# MySQL trigger with python

Tags: python, mysql, node.js, triggers, python-3.3

I have a python script( script 1) that adds elements in a table in MySQL database using mysql.connector module, and I have another python script( script 2) that reads data from that table, I want to put a trigger on that table and each time a new element is added script 2 notice the new added element and display a message on the console.

I'm looking for something like the nodeJS npm package "mysql-events" that watches a MySQL database and runs callbacks on matched functions

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question. But I was searching the same today for my work and came across this link - [mysql - Run python script on Database event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23382499/run-python-script-on-database-event). Look at the answer which has been submitted by the person asking question. It might help you/someone.