# How to set an event scheduler to check if the is new row in a given Mysql table

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading, events, triggers

I want to create a function in python that check every 1 minute if there is a new entry (new row) in Mysql workbench database table (tblx).

If there is a new entry, my function must call another function that do some computation in a field of (tblx) that have High priority. NOTE there could also be other entries within that one minute with low priority. so the computation function will start first with high priority entries then low priority entries.
And compution should be done in FIFO

once it this function finish computation, it must return status in tblx table. in tblx status field.

can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

This might help for the

> a function to check every 1 minute if there is a new entry

[Run python script on Database event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23382499/run-python-script-on-database-event)